# how to run the rails example code present in github?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to run the code present in https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic_example.git but could not able to do. I have tried a few examples before and it went so good. I could not do the same with this. There is no gemfile and probably few things are missing. Somebody tell me how to execute this particular example.

Comment: what have you tried? What was the error message you got? We can only help you if you at least had a go at it yourself and can tell us a bit more about where you got stuck. I recognise that this question was a long time ago - but when you ask a question, you really need to know that you need to provide these things so we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last commit is 3 years old on that repo so I doubt it is compatible with bundle and Rails 3. I would advise you to try [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) for authentication instead os authlogic as with Rails3 that is the defacto auth gem.
Example applications: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/Example-Applications

Comment: I have tried  https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/Example-Applications and there is no activation process included.

Comment: You can see a howto on this link: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-:confirmable-to-Users